# Better to return List from HashMap or keep List in memory?

Tags: java, android, performance

I see many results for returning a List from a HashMap, so no problem there, but I am curious to know if it is a better option to always do this vs keeping objects in a list themselves in my scenario below.

I have a bunch of Widget objects (having an `id`(`UUID`), a `title`(`String`), and a `priority`(`int`)) in a singleton class, `WidgetStore`. I am going to use them to populate a `RecyclerView`. The `Fragment` wants a List for the View, but I also have a method to return a single Widget by `id`. To keep the Widgets in a list means I have to loop through them looking for the one with the given `id`, so I figure it's much faster to have them in a `HashMap<UUID, Widget>`. Not only is it fast to look up by `id`, but I can also just return a List `object` when asked. Is this more or less optimal? Is there a way I can find out for myself without bothering you? (Question is for my own personal edification, I am trying to learn the inner-workings a little better here.)

Here is the class for the `WidgetStore`:

```
public class WidgetStore {
    private static WidgetStore sWidgetStore;
    // private final List<Widget> mWidgets; // Use hashmap instead, better?
    private final HashMap<UUID, Widget> mIdMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static WidgetStore get(Context context) {
        // Singleton: if one exists, return it; otherwise, create it
        if (sWidgetStore == null) {
            sWidgetStore = new WidgetStore(context);
        }
        return sWidgetStore;
    }

    private WidgetStore(Context context) {
        // Singleton: only access this class with get()

        // mWidgets = new ArrayList<>(); // Use hashmap instead

        // Widget factory
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            Widget widget = new Widget();
            widget.setTitle("Widget #" + i);
            widget.setPriority((int) (Math.random() * 100d) % 3); // Random-ish-ly
            // mWidgets.add(widget); // Use hasmap instead
            mIdMap.put(widget.getId(), widget);
        }
    }

    public List<Widget> getWidgets() {
        // TODO find out if faster to always create new list from hashmap or
        // also keep a list around in memory (seems fast on good hardware...)
        List<Widget> list = new ArrayList<>(mIdMap.values());
        return list;
    }

    public Widget getWidget(UUID id) {
        Widget widget = mIdMap.get(id);
        if (widget == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return widget;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about returning `values()` directly (as a `Collection`) instead of copying it to a list?

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally you shouldn't worry much about optimizing your code until later in development and you realize there is a performance issue. But if you're learning about want to know more about the more optimal option, yes it sounds like a HashMap or similar Map.

Having a method to get the values as a list may be helpful depending on if you know the id for a widget you want or not, or if you need to check some other property of the widget to ID it.

As far as doing profiling on your own, there's a couple methods. You can just throw in some manual Log statements using `System.currentTimeMillis()` like this:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
Widget widget = widgetStore.get(id);
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - now;
Log.i("WidgetStorePerformance", duration);
```

That's the low-tech solution. You can also look into adding Trace method calls into the WidgetStore code you want to profile.

```
public Widget getWidget(UUID id) {
    Trace.beginSection("WidgetStore");
    Widget widget = mIdMap.get(id);
    if (widget == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Trace.endSection();
    return widget;
}
```

Then use [this tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/systrace)

Comment: Thanks! I'm teaching myself so it often feels like there is probably a ton that I don't know lurking just below my decisions. I get the idea that there are things I could do/want that would change the decision, but I often have no idea of my instincts are right or not. Good to know I was on the right track here. Also kind of excited to try out Trace.

Comment: @TrivialCase no problem. Getting to know the inner-workings of things makes you a better developer so good on you.